# Running stored procedure and populating values in SOAPUI

Tags: wcf, load-testing, soapui

I have a load test that needs to send a unique value Id for sending request and then waiting for response against that Id. I want to execute database procedure to generate new Id everytime and populate that Id in request attribute of xml that I send to service. Any idea is this possible in SOAPUI and if yes How can I do this. I have only SOAPUI. Is scripting available only in SOAPUI PRO. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it really need to be unique, or just "unique for this run"?  If it's the latter, make a DataGen and populate it with a list of your unique IDs.  Or get a little fancier and make the datagen return some text plus a sequence, like this:

TESTGUID${#SEQ}

results:

TESTGUID1
TESTGUID2
TESTGUID3
....
TESTGUID99999

My SEQ persists between sessions, so it's never generated the same key twice.

Comment: So for each run, use datetime for the first part of the fake GUID. Like this:
TESTGUID201203011648${#SEQ}